# Webservice standards and DTDs

Tags: facebook, web-services, google-maps, standards, dtd

While brainstorming about six years ago, I had what I thought was a great idea: in the future there could be webservice standards and DTDs that effectively turn the web into a decentralized knowledgebase.  I listed several areas where I thought this could be applied, one of which was:

> **For making data avail. directly from a business's website: open hours, locations, and contact phone numbers.** Suggest a web service standard by which businesses have a standard URL extended off the main (base) URL for there website, at which is located a webservice.  That webservice as well has a standardized set of services for downloading a list of their locations, contact telephone numbers, and business hours.

It's interesting looking back at these notes now since this is **not** how things have evolved.  Instead of businesses putting this information on only their website then letting any search engine or other data aggregator to crawl it, they are updating it separately on their website, their Facebook page, and Google Maps.  Facebook and Google Maps, due to their popularity, have become the solution to the problem I though my idea would solve.

Is the way things are better than the way I thought they could be?  If so then why doesn't my idea fit the reality?  If not then what's holding my idea back from being realized?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of this information *is* available via APIs, that doesn't mean that it doesn't get put other places as well, through a variety of means. For example, a company may expose information via an API, and their Facebook app might use that API to populate a Facebook page.

Also, various [microformats](http://microformats.org/) are in use that encapsulate some of this information.

The biggest obstacle is agreeing on what meta-information should be exposed, how it should be exposed, and how it should be accessed.

Comment: The scenario you described ("expose information via an API, and their Facebook app might use that API to populate a Facebook page") is hardly an option for the vast majority of mom-and-pop shops out there.

Comment: @HappyNomad So? But of course it's an option, there are a ton of mom & pop sites for which doing so would be trivial, and a FB presence is essentially free. (Not to mention if they already have a website, they could use the same site to serve up an FB iframe app.)

Comment: Please link to blog post that shows how to easily do all this.

Comment: @HappyNomad Do all what? A FB app is a plain web app that lives in an iframe. A service is just something that returns data in a known format; it could even be a static page.

Comment: Geez... that sounds so easy I'm sure everyone with a FB page can do it

Comment: @HappyNomad If you're being sarcastic, I don't understand why. If there's already a website, running it on FB is configuration only.

Comment: Sounds interesting... wish I knew how to do it.

Comment: @Happynomad Just get a book on FB app development, or follow a beginner's tutorial. Once you get into using the FB API beyond the basics ut can become a pain, but mom and pop probably don't require deep integration on FB or off. The basic JS API is probably enough.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4605/discussion-between-happynomad-and-dave-newton)